# JSON update single value in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON array in the MySQL `payment` table `details` column. I need to update a single value of this JSON array. What is the procedure to update JSON using MySQL?

**JSON Array**

```
{"items":[{"ca_id":18,"appointment_date":"2018-09-15 15:00:00","service_name":"Software Installation / Up-gradation","service_price":165}],"coupon":{"code":"GSSPECIAL","discount":"10","deduction":"0.00"},"subtotal":{"price":165,"deposit":0},"tax_in_price":"included","adjustments":[{"reason":"Over-time","amount":"20","tax":"0"}]}
```

I need to update the **appointment _date** `2018-09-15 15:00:00` to `2018-09-28 15:00:00`.

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using `PHP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure MySQL JSON way of doing this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = JSON_REPLACE(col, '$.items[0].appointment_date', '2018-09-28 15:00:00');
```

The best I could come up with is to address the first element of the JSON array called `items`, and then update the `appointment_date` field in that array element.

Here is a demo showing that the JSON replacement syntax/logic is working:

### Demo

But, you could equally as well have done this JSON work in your PHP layer.  It might make more sense to do this in PHP.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen maybe it's not working in mysql version: 5.6.40. Am I right?

Comment: I didn't know your version, but assumed your version had support for at least the basic JSON functions.  You might have no other choice then but to do this in PHP (not the the worst thing at all however).  I will leave this answer up as a valid option for those with a newer version of MySQL.

Comment: One more thing: Consider upgrading to the latest MySQL 8+ which, in addition to having JSON support, also supports many analytic functions previously not available to MySQL.

Comment: My version is 5.6.40. I have found an documentation in the GitHub, where I can see the `JSON_REPLACE` function has started from version 5.7. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in php then, steps to follow:

1. Select the respective column from the table
2. Use `json_decode` to convert the string to array
3. Now you have the json object, apply your modifications
4. Use `json_encode` to convert your json object back to string
5. Save this string in table